# Do food item effects stack?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Doing some experimentation I consumed two of the same item of food from my inventory and when I returned the game screen I only had the remaining time of a single item.

So eating two 'Meat' with a 10s vitality regen timer, you'll only get 10s of regen.

As the duration doesn't stack, is the effect of eating multiple food items cumulative? Will I get double the regen in the same amount of time? Or are extra food items just 'lost'.

Comment: The question was correctly answered [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/236429/6728).

Answer (score 0):

No, when they stack you see two different timers. However I am not sure as to how it is done. I was doing it for about half the game and recently i cant do it, Im not sure if it was an ability i had equipped or a piece of equipment, if you do find the answer let me know, because you can consume two SEPERATE food items and regain health much faster

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this?

Comment: I noticed food and drink have separate timers. I do not know if consuming two foods increases the rate at which you heal.

Answer (score -1):

one food, one drink

eg. water and meat combined.