# Does vitality regeneration stack?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Regenerating health on "Death March" difficulty can take a while if you have a rather big health pool and no perk to regenerate health (e.g. using Quen).

Apart from potions I use food to regenerate health. However, it can take quite a long time if I have to eat Dried Fruit And Nuts 5 times. I eat one, wait 5 seconds, open the inventory again (or use the quick slot) and wait 5 more seconds.

**Therefore I'd like to know if vitality regeneration stacks by eating multiple foods.**

For example (numbers not accurate):

- I eat 1 "Dried Fruit and Nuts"

  - 100 vitality restored over 5 seconds.
- I eat 2 "Dried Fruit and Nuts" then leave the inventory screen. What is the outcome?

  1. Regenerate 100 vitality over 5 seconds.
  2. Regenerate 200 vitality over 5 seconds.

Which way does it work? Assuming it works like 1. I would have to keep opening the menu, eating 1 piece of food, opening the menu again and eat the next. I don't like placing food in my two quick slots because I usually save those slots for my most important potions.

---

**Edit 1:**

After having a look at the question to which this question is flagged as a duplicate I concluded that there are contradictions on how the stacking works.

Two theories that need proof (proven in Edit 2):

1. Vitality regeneration does stack, no matter what you eat/drink.
2. Vitality regeneration only stacks if the foods consumed are not of the same type (e.g. 2 x Nuts do not stack, but 1 x cow milk + 1 x nuts will stack).

I will test this when I get home looking at the numbers (vitality information on the inventory screen).

Right now, everything points to theory 2 since theory 1 would make you invincible for a short time if you stuff 20 roasted chickens down Geralt's throat.

---

**Edit 2:**

I can confirm theory 2.

Eating one raw meat regenerated 508 hp over 5 seconds.

Eating one raw meat and one cow's milk added two regeneration indicators to the UI and regenerating 1432 hp over 30 seconds. The timer for raw meat ran 5 seconds while the cow's milk timer ran 30 seconds.

This also confirms that different foods have different intensities of regeneration. While raw meat regenerates 508 hp over 5 seconds, cow's milk regenerated 924 hp over 30 seconds.

Oddly, drinking cow's milk without eating at the same time regenerated 931 hp.

- Raw meat: 508 hp
- Cow's milk: 931 hp
- 1 x raw meat + 1 x cow's milk: 1432 hp (instead of predicted 508 + 931 = 1439 hp)

I did the tests at level 30.

Comment: You'll also find some information in [this related answer from me](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/222440/4103)

Comment: The answer from @MadScientist is actually good and correct, I'd recommend to check that one out instead of the one which was marked as duplicate since its wrong.

Comment: I can tell that it works like in edit point 2. Tried that with bread and 1 bread healed the same amount like 20 breads

Comment: @Nitro.de Can you confirm that drinking 1 x milk (20 hp/s) and eating 1 x nuts (20 hp/s) will result in 40 hp/s?

Comment: @exa i can confirm that they stack but i cannot tell if your example will result in 40hp/s

Comment: If milk heals for 30 seconds and nuts for 5 seconds, my current assumption is that 40 hp/s will apply for the first 5 seconds and 20 hp/s (from the milk) for the remaining 25 seconds. I can tell you more in a few hours when I tested it. Geralt will have to run off those pounds he will gain tonight.

Comment: As a side note: Ekhidna decoction is all you need. I never ever use food and also no other potions that heals on Death March. Use that decoction and you are full health by just jumping around a couple of seconds

Comment: @IvoBeckers I only used quen to refill my hp on death march xD

Comment: @Nitro.de yeah I forgot about that. I would even say that Quen is even better than using food. But maybe that's just becuase I hate using food xD

Comment: @Nitro.de Do you mean the alternate sign mode? That's a good idea.

Comment: @Exa jip I mean he [alternate sign mode active shield](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Active+Shield)

Comment: Yep, I'm still waiting for a decent answer to my question. I was hoping that directing people there would get some better answers which I could accept :)

Comment: I've updated my question to mark it as a duplicate of this question instead, as this one has had way more attention.

Comment: @Exa, looking at your second edit I think I can explain the difference between your predicted and actual healing. You forgot that Geralt has a 1hp/s natural healing always!, even on DM. So it is highly likely that Raw meat healing is a actual nice round 500 and Cow's milk 900. This would mean that when timed correctly the results would be: 505, 930 and 1430

Comment: @IvoBeckers Thanks, didn't know that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, Yes and No.

There are 3 different types of "food": Eatable, Drinkable and Potion. These stack with each other. So you can drink Cow Milk and eat Nuts and these effects will stack. If you eat 1 Nut and then 1 raw meat, the remaining healing effect of the nut will vanish. Otherwise it would be way to easy since you could eat 20 Nuts and were unkillable for 5 seconds.